# How can I balance between a formal and informal tone?

Tags: style, creative-writing

I want my writings to be "to-the-point" and no-nonsense, but at the same time, I want them to be entertaining so that they grip attention. By entertaining I don't only mean funny, slang-ish, or humourous.

So how do I strike a balance between a formal tone and an informal tone? I end up writing either full-formal or full-informal.

Comment: Hi, and welcome to Writers. What's the context for your writing? Blog posts? A novel? Academic writing? Business? This will help us answer your question.

Comment: I've put this on hold until Lauren's question can be answered; will reopen when we have context.

Comment: Ah, sure. I author articles on a certain topic. I just need the directives for ideal article posts that usually have proper structure and logical backing of assertions.